# "Fatal error: Invalid string length" when serving large files via grunt

Tags: javascript, video, gruntjs, yeoman

This has been working fine until "yesterday." I don't recall installing anything new on my dev machine. I can see nothing in my recent code changes that might have caused this behavior. This started happening right after a system restart. Running on Windows. My IDE is WebStorm.

I have a Javascript project which has a file with some large .mp4 video files in it. I open a command window and run

```
> grunt serve
```

and the browser comes up fine. If I browse to the resource:

```
http://localhost:9000/Themes/a1.mp4
```

the video plays in the browser. If I browse to

```
http://localhost:9000/Themes/a2.mp4
```

after about 6 seconds the error message in the title appears in my command window and the browser spins on, eventually timing out with `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

I have a variety of .mp4 files. Only the larger ones cause this issue (>400MB) smaller ones (<200MB) don't cause this issue.

Here's the relevant connect section of the gruntfile.js file. This was generated by Yeoman.

```
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect.static('test'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      port: 9001,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect.static('test'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }
  }
},
[... snip ...]
grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
if (target === 'dist') {
  return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
}

grunt.task.run([
  'clean:server',
  'wiredep',
  'bowerRequirejs:app',
  'concurrent:server',
  'postcss:server',
  'connect:livereload',
  'watch'
]);
});
```

I've tried using grunt-connect instead. It serves the larger video file fine, but I don't know how to configure it to serve the same range of folders that the extract above is serving.